# How to add SQL where and limit query in PHP?

Tags: php, sql

I want to show table order where `status = 'confirmed'`, but my code doesn't work:

```
public function getdataorderconfirmed($limit, $offset){
    if($offset == '') {
        $sql = $this->db->query**("SELECT * FROM orderan where status = 'confirmed' LIMIT '.$limit.' 
            OFFSET 0 ");**
    return $sql->result();
    }
    else{
        **$sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM orderan where status = 'confirmed' LIMIT '.$limit.' 
        OFFSET '.$offset.'");**
    return $sql->result();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're mixing single and double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` don't need their values quoted because they're numbers, so remove the single quotes around them here:

```
$sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM orderan where status = 'confirmed'
                         LIMIT $limit OFFSET 0");
```

And here:

```
$sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM orderan where status = 'confirmed'
                         LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the query as following, you can use PHP variables as it is if in double quotes, there is no need to concat:

```
public function getdataorderconfirmed($limit, $offset){
            if($offset == '') {
                $sql = $this->db->query**("SELECT * FROM orderan where status = 'confirmed' LIMIT $limit OFFSET 0");**
            return $sql->result();
            }
            else{
                **$sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM orderan where status = 'confirmed' LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset");**
            return $sql->result();
            }
        }
```